# Comparative condition in table

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I want to the  below excel sheet if **Total Deposit** table is less than to **Total Cost** table - it's automatically subtract at **Manager Get** table, and if **Total Deposit** table is greater than to **Total Cost** table- it's automatically subtract at **Customer Get** table. If **Total Cost** & **Total** **Deposit** are equal then the both of  **Customer get** and **Manager Get** table show **NO Due**.*I am extremely sorry,i could not upload excel snap-short image for my poor reputation . but i did  it by html code . To clarify my question plz run the the code*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Total Cost</th>
    <th>Total deposit</th>  
    <th>Customer Get</th>
    <th>Manager Get</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2700</td>
    <td>2500</td>  
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2500</td>
    <td>2900</td>  
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2300</td>
    <td>2300</td>  
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>

  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Took me a bit before I realized you were just showing us the excel table using HTML.  I haven't see anyone do that yet.

Comment: I am extremely sorry,i could not upload excel snap-short image for my poor reputation .For this reason  i did it by html code .@chancea

Comment: I actually think its kinda cool.  This is the only way I have been ever able to directly copy and paste something from SO into excel.

Comment: Whatever! Firstly i would like to thank  you for response . I guess that you solve my problem @chancea .

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you have 3 conditions:

> if **Total Deposit** table is less than to **Total Cost** table - it's automatically subtract at **Manager Get table**
>
> if **Total Deposit** table is greater than to **Total Cost** table- it's
>   automatically subtract at **Customer Get** table
>
> If **Total Cost** & **Total Deposit** are equal then the both of **Customer get** and **Manager Get** table show **NO Due**

I believe we can accomplish that using 2 formulas.  Assuming the data starts in A1:

Formula for **Customer Get**:

```
=IF(B2>A2,B2-A2,IF(B2=A2,"NO Due","-"))
```

Formula for **Manager Get**:

```
=IF(B2<A2,A2-B2,IF(B2=A2,"NO Due","-"))
```

You can then autofill the formula down:

```
Total Cost     Total deposit        Customer Get                              Manager Get
2700           2500                 =IF(B2>A2,B2-A2,IF(B2=A2,"NO Due","-"))   =IF(B2<A2,A2-B2,IF(B2=A2,"NO Due","-"))
2500           2900                 =IF(B3>A3,B3-A3,IF(B3=A3,"NO Due","-"))   =IF(B3<A3,A3-B3,IF(B3=A3,"NO Due","-"))
2300           2300                 =IF(B4>A4,B4-A4,IF(B4=A4,"NO Due","-"))   =IF(B4<A4,A4-B4,IF(B4=A4,"NO Due","-"))
```

And the result looks like:

```
Total Cost  Total deposit   Customer Get    Manager Get
2700        2500            -               200
2500        2900            400             -
2300        2300            NO Due          NO Due
```